# Remove label from SIgnUp form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to extend the default form and remove the labels for Django-allauth signup form. Most labels are removed successfully, but I'm not able to remove the label for the email field.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile


class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
     gender = forms.CharField(max_length=1, label='Gender')
     first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='First Name')
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Last Name')
     birthday = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Birthday')
     location = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Location')

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': 'autofocus'})

         #remove labels for fields
         for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.label
            field.label =''


    class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',  'gender', 'birthday', 'location')

    def signup(self, request, user):
         # Save your user
         user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
         user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
         user.save()

         # Save your profile
         profile = Profile()
         profile.user = user
         profile.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']
         profile.location = self.cleaned_data['location']
         profile.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
         profile.save()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True, auto_now=False)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
    )
    # gender can take only one of the GENDER_CHOICES options
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                              verbose_name='Gender')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

**Rendered SignUp form** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you forgot adding

```
email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
```

into the SignupForm fields?

also add 'email' into

```
fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',  'gender', 'birthday', 'location', 'email')
```

Comment: Don't think so as the email field label shows up (see image above). I'll try this out anyway. Thks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the email label still appears, with it's placeholder set to None.

Comment: Hi, is this email field belong to user model or profile model? I don't see the email see this email field in the profile model form fields, but you use `profile.email = self.cleaned_data['email']` to set the email field. So I am wondering what is you profile model looks like..thanks

Comment: Hi lboro, I've included the models. The profile.email is not required as it is handed in the [BaseSignupForm](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py). Someone has commented about this issue as seen [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1501)